# warning messages when developing R package

Tags: r

When I develop a function in R, the following message appears when I click Build and Reload: 
Warning messages:

```
1: package ‘formattable’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
3: package ‘Amelia’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
4: package ‘car’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
5: package ‘pscl’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
6: package ‘gplots’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
7: package ‘ROCR’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
8: package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
9: package ‘roxygen2’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
10: package ‘miniCRAN’ was built under R version 3.4.1
```

How to overcome this problem ?

Comment: What version of R are you on? How does it compare to 3.4.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for this is, as the message says, that you are using different libraries built under different versions of R. This could mean that it could break at some point due to version differences and R is letting you know this. To solve this you could update your packages to the most recent version. This can be done manually by running:

```
update.packages()
```

or if you want to update them all:

```
update.packages(ask=FALSE)
```

To update one specific "PACKAGE"

```
install.packages("PACKAGE")
```

although this might take some time and some packages might not be available up to the same version. You could use **devtools** to install an specific VERSION of the PACKAGE

```
require(devtools)
install_version("PACKAGE", version = "VERSION", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

---

If you do not want to do this you can suppress the warning message by using:

```
suppressWarnings()
```

or set warning messages off (might not be a good idea):

```
options(warn = -1)
```

use

```
options(warn = 0)
```

to set them on again.

```
?warning
```

for help.

Comment: Conditional on not being able to update to the latest version, my advice is to use the MS CRAN repository snapshots, like https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2017-07-21/. Go to the last day of availability for a version of R by changing the URL and use that as the repo.

Comment: This last comment is totally out of date.